# Selective Denoise

Tags: rendering

guys!

Do you know if it is possible to render an animation with denoise, but only on chosen objects?
I want to make an animation with a freezing object, the particles are small and if denoiser is turned on, they get really messy, and at the same time I cannot give it more samples since it already takes a long time to render.

Do you have any ideas if this is possible? Or how would you do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Compositor, first thing disable the *Denoise* option and enable the *Film > Transparent* option in the *Render* panel. Then in the *Layer* panel enable the *Denoising Data* option:

[image]

You can do it with the *Cryptomatte* or with the *View Layers*. In the *Compositor*, do the mix between the *Render Layers* (with a *Color > Alpha Over*), create a *Filter > Denoise* node and plug the Image, *Denoising Normal* and *Denoising Albedo* into the *Denoise* node:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!